# MYSQL equivalent to Sybase ASE command?

Tags: mysql, sap-ase

Is there a equivalent way to see the execution plans from MYSQL like the `set showplan on` command in Sybase ASE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) statement.

Comment: thanks m8, that's what I needed :) I'll accept it in 8m time :P